# print splits page at top

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a print.css it splits the header between two pages and I can't figure out how to where I'm going wrong

print.css

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 8.5in 11in;
  }

  html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body > * {
    display: none;
  }

  body {
    display: inline;
  }

  #preview {
    display: inline;
    font: 12pt Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    line-height: 1.3;
  }

  #preview h3 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  #preview button {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

html (preview gets filled with javascript)

```
<body style="background-color: white; height: 100%; width: 100%" onload="buildForm()">
  <aside id="overlay"> <!--overlay display is block-->
    <section onclick="edit()"></section>
    <div id="preview"></div>
  </aside>
</body>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0cxd3su/1/) of everything but it's not going to work since it's an electron app and requires some node modules

**Update**

Got it working with this css

```
@media print {
  html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  body > * {
    display: none;
  }
  body {
    display: inline;
  }
  #preview {
    font: 12pt Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    line-height: 1.3;
  }
  #preview h3 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  #preview button {
    display: none;
  }
}

@page {
  size: A4;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it

```
 @page {
    size: 8.5in 11in;
  }
```

Is most likely the culprit. Its still viewing it in the web world and not the print preview world.

Also my advice is to have the standard print shiv before anything -

```
.its.visible-mobile{display: none !important;}
* { background: transparent !important; color: black !important; box-shadow:none !important; text-shadow: none !important; filter:none !important; -ms-filter: none !important; border:none !important; } /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
a, a:visited { text-decoration: underline; }
a:link:after, a:visited:after { content: ""; }
.ir a:after, a[href^="javascript:"]:after, a[href^="#"]:after { content: ""; }
header .ir a:after, a[href^="javascript:"]:after, a[href^="#"]:after { content: ""; }
```

Comment: Increasing those values did change the size but I had this working yesterday with those values and I just can't figure out what I changed.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle of everything. The buildPreview() function builds the html that I am trying to print. It's near the top of the javascript

Comment: before anything there are some missing things - check the console looks like theres some missing things: ``var csv = require('fast-csv');`` this is not being read

Comment: Since this is an electron app you can use node modules like that. Everything works fine except for the printing.

Comment: if you say so... then try adjusting the page snippet like so : ``@page {
  size: A4;
}`` also you might just have to remove it out of the print media

Comment: Alright I moved `@page` out of the print media and changed the size to `A4`. I also added in `body { display: inline }` as well as `*, *:before, *:after { display: inherit }` and it's working as expected now. I'm not sure what happened since I found the code I was using yesterday and it wasn't working either. Glad that's over with.

Comment: @SirParselot nice to hear. Can you approve answer?